# Updating PXBool Field from Sort Function on INTranSplit

Tags: c#, acumatica

I've created a custom page in Acumatica that pulls in several pieces of information about ItemLotSerial (users can filter based on Stock Item + LotSerialNbr).

We currently pull in all transaction for INTranSplit to ensure we can display it's current location.

I also want to be able to display if it's in inventory based on it's current location.

During the filter process:

```
public IEnumerable inventoryLocation()
{
    PXView select = new PXView(this, true, InventoryLocation.View.BqlSelect);
    Int32 totalrow = 0;
    Int32 startrow = PXView.StartRow;
    List<object> result = select.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters, PXView.Searches,
        PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters, ref startrow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalrow);


    INTranSplit latest = null;
    if (result.Count > 0)
    {
        //We need to perform a custom order in order to get to the latest record.
        latest = result.First() as INTranSplit;
        foreach (INTranSplit row in result)
        {
            if (latest.CreatedDateTime.Value < row.CreatedDateTime.Value)
            {
                latest = row;

            }
        }
        /*Here I fire the Event */
        ItemLotSerial.Cache.SetValueExt<INItemLotSerialExt.inInventory> ItemLotSerial.Current, (latest.Qty * latest.InvtMult) > 0);
    }
    return new List<object> { latest };
}
```

I want to update a UnboundField Boolean which I added to an extension class of ItemLotSerial if something is in Inventory or Not.

When firing this event, I can see it bubbles through the events (as it should.) But, it doesn't update the checkbox on the UI.

Things I've tried to get the field to update is

1. RequestRefresh
2. Refreshing the Cache via FieldUpdatedEvent on the new field.

Only one thing is actually forcing the field to update. We have several events related to INItemLotSerial, when another event fires it will update.

Some information about the field: it's not going to be editable.

**If you could help me figure out why the UI is not updating when firing SetValueExt, that would be great.**

Comment: I don't think the DataView delegate is the recommended place to raise events. What I would do in the delegate is use GetExtension on ItemLotSerial and set the field without SetValue: latestExt.InInventory.= (latest.Qty * latest.InvtMult) > 0. If you need to force fire events, you could do it later in RowInserted/Updated etc. using RaiseFieldUpdated

Comment: The DataView delegate builds the DataView, event will later work on that DataView. Therefore I would suggest not to fire events on the DataView before it's constructor (DataView delegate) has finished running.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Moved the logic out of the delegate. So I decided to move some logic to a INTranSplit_RowSelected(PXCache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs). I grab the current record of INItemLotSerial, grab the extension, do the multiplication problem then raise INItemLotSerial.Cache.RaiseFieldUpdated and it doesn't seem to be doing anything on the UI. Should this be happening?

Comment: If you set the value outside of the delegate like in rowselected then you should use SetValue or SetValueExt to have it updated on UI. SetValueExt will call events like FieldUpdated while SetValue will only change the value without raising these events.

Comment: I started using both like within a few but I'm having to call it like INItemLotSerial.Cache.SetValueExt<INItemLotSerialExt.inInventory>(INItemLotSerial.Current, (split.Qty * split.InvtMult) > 0); But, for some odd reason, it's still not updating the UI field. But, when I check something related to the object, the field will get updated.Strange, right?

Comment: Not sure what's going on here. You can attempt to force it in various ways: setting CommitChanges=True on the field, set field in various ways directly and using setvalue, update dataview with current record InventoryLocation.Update(INItemLotSeria‌​l.Current), suggest refresh view with InventoryLocation.View.RequestRefresh()

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that result grid is bound to the **InventoryLocation** data view, which returns only INTranSplit records, I would suggest one of following options:

1. Change declaration of the **InventoryLocation** data view and implemetnation of its delegate to return `PXResultset<INTranSplit, INItemLotSerial>`. You should decalre **InventoryLocation** view as ***INTranSplit*** INNER/LEFT JOIN **INItemLotSerial** and yield return `PXResultset<INTranSplit, INItemLotSerial>` composed from **INTranSplit** and **INItemLotSerial** records. In data view delegate you should update ***INItemLotSerialExt.inInventory*** field for the **INItemLotSerial** records returned by the delegate
2. Make zero changes to the **InventoryLocation** data view and declare your unbound **InInventory** field within the **INTranSplit** DAC extension, instead of the **INItemLotSerial** extension class

Based on the details you provided, it seems that changes to the ***INItemLotSerialExt.inInventory*** field are only reflected in the UI after you update **INItemLotSerial** record in the cache...